# Toad â‚¬ to € symbol Oracle euro UTF-8

Tags: oracle, utf-8, symbols, toad, euro

I am using Toad 9.0.1.8.

A table in a column was showing a euro `€` symbol as `â‚¬`

I've tried changing the environment variable `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` in my windows machine, I've also tried using `American_America.UTF8` and `American_America.WE8ISO8859P1`, yet it did not get resolved, I'm still seeing the characters but not a euro symbol. Every time i changed the env var, I restarted Toad.

Could somebody help? Tried some solutions by searching online, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a character set issue in you DB? From [this](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/623437) thread it seems to be a problem with DB settings.

Also [some suggestion](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/f/10/t/8852.aspx) on charset issues suggest upgrading to version 10 of `Toad` if that is an option since it's a unicode release.

Comment: Upgraded to Toad 11.6 and OS to Win7, Still the problem persists!

Comment: The DB lead also turned out into nothing?

Comment: Yes, the DB people were also unable to help!